# Downloading or requesting a page using a proxy list?

Tags: perl, proxy

I was wondering if that was possible to request an internet page from its server via a proxy taken from a proxy list.

I don't really know all the exact terms, so I'll just explain what I want: say there is a feature in a website which counts IPs or something alike (perhaps cookies), such as visitors counter. I'd like to "fool" it by "entering" the page using many proxies.
I could use something like Tor, but that's too much work - I only want to visit a page, let the counter or whatever in the page know that I visited, and that's all.

I don't really know which tags to add, but I had some little experiments with Perl so I think that could be a good direction, although I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perl would suit nicely. You need to be able to read a file (containing the proxy list) and call a command (curl can use a proxy parameter).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately I don't know much about said "curl", so could you please explain a bit further on?

Comment: curl is a small application that can transfer data from and to the web. It can visit the page for you, and use a proxy. Checkout [its manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: Well, I spent the last hour reading about and and I reached the sad conclusion that I probably just don't know enough to deal with it. I couldn't even install the Module on my Perl. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = shift || 'http://www.google.com';

my $a = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$a->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$a->timeout(20);
while (<DATA>) {
  $a->proxy( ['http'], $_ );
  warn "Failed to get page with proxy $_\n"
    unless $a->get( $url )->is_success;
}

__DATA__
http://85.214.142.3:8080
http://109.230.245.167:80
http://211.222.204.1:80
```

The code doesn't require much explanations. [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) allows specifying a proxy server.

Loop through a list of proxies, get the wanted page and you're done.